# PHP file opens empty when downloaded

Tags: php, file, pdo

On my website I get a specific file from the database that the user submitted. The problem I am getting is that when i download the file that was submitted, I get an empty "docx or pptx or txt" file. I tried submitted a word doc with text inside and when I downloaded it, i got the same result(an empty file). I believe the problem is with when i actually retrieve the file from the user and send it to the database. Here is my code for retrieving and downloading the file.

Retrieve File

```
                $bio_name = $_FILES['biography']['name'];
                $bio_tmp = $_FILES['biography']['tmp_name'];
                $bio_size = $_FILES['biography']['size'];
                $bio_type = $_FILES['biography']['type'];
                $ext = pathinfo($bio_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


                if($ext=="pdf"||$ext=="PDF"||$ext=="doc"||$ext=="DOC"||$ext=="docx"||$ext=="DOCX"
                ||$ext=="XLS"||$ext=="xls"||$ext=="XLSX"||$ext=="xlsx"||$ext=="xlsm"||$ext=="XLSM" || $ext=="txt"||$ext=="TXT" || $ext=="pptx"||$ext=="PPTX"){
                    $fp = fopen($bio_tmp, 'r');
                $content = fread($fp, filesize($bio_tmp));
                $content = addslashes($content);
                fclose($fp);


                }else{


                    echo "<script>
                alert('ERROR: This file format is not supported');
                window.location.href='speakerform.php';
                </script>";
                }
```

Download File

```
$speaker_id = 13;
    $stmtSpeaker = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM formdata WHERE user_id= :speaker_id");
    $stmtSpeaker->bindParam(':speaker_id', $speaker_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmtSpeaker->execute();
    $formData = $stmtSpeaker->fetch();

    $size = $formData['bio_size'];
        $type = $formData['bio_type'];
        $file = $formData['bio_filename'];
        $content = $formData['bio_tmp'];
         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

Comment: make sure the path you have for the file name does indeed correspond with the real path. Error reporting and `var_dump()` will help you here. Check permissions also.

Comment: I don't send it to  file path though. You mean like in my file directory or in phpmyadmin?

Comment: so the file content is coming from a BLOB then, is it? what's the value of `$formData['bio_filename']`?

Comment: Yea from the database. I use var_dump on the filename and i got nothing. The value is just the filename "text.png"

Comment: the file needs to exist somewhere. See  what https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php does, same for error reporting.

Comment: The problem is I am not getting an error, just that it gives an empty file. And when you said "file needs to exist somewhere" do you mean i should store each file submitted into a file directory? and retrieve it from there?

Comment: *"do you mean i should store each file submitted into a file directory? and retrieve it from there?"* - That is exactly it. Look at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php on how to do this.

Comment: I will try that out right now and get back to you, thank you

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: Wow! It worked perfectly, can you please post your answer for me to rate. Thank you again @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: You're welcome, it has been done. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wow! It worked perfectly, can you please post your answer for me to rate. Thank you again @FunkFortyNiner – Jagr

As requested and pulled from my comment(s):

> *"do you mean i should store each file submitted into a file directory? and retrieve it from there?"* - That is exactly it. (me)

The manual on uploading files https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php is what you need to use.

Here is an example pulled from the manual:

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Then apply that to your code and then use that reference to upload the file and then the file's reference itself in the fetching query statement.